# time_range in faceook insights v2.5 issue

Tags: facebook-insights, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I'm compiling a URL like

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<campaign id>/insights?since=2015-08-10&until=2015-11-13&time_increment=1&access_token=<valid token>
```

This query, even in GRAPH explorer, gives back data which is obviously outside the given date range. Putting something weired as "until" date causes an error,
but I do not get it working in a way, that the result is within the given range. I.e. I get rows for "2015-04-21".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the time_range parameter to the request, for example:

```
&time_range[since]=2016-02-15&time_range[until]=2016-02-16
```

Comment: I will give that a try; did you try this in Graph explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Use insights as an object instead of a field~

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<campaign id>/insights/since=2015-08-10&until=2015-11-13&access_token=<valid token>
```

Comment: This is not a valid URL syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
ad_account_id/ads?fields=insights.time_range({"since":"2017-11-01","until":"2017-11-23"}){ad_id,reach,ad_name,impressions,clicks}&breakdowns=publisher_platform
```

use `insights.time_range({"since":"2017-11-01","until":"2017-11-23"})`. it's working for me.